# An error in the Ubuntu documentation, but nowhere to report it and no way to edit it

Tags: kvm-virtualization, documentation, ubuntu-wiki

I have just wasted a lot of time trying to edit an error on this page -  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation - or at least tell someone about the error. But that all seems impossible. For instance, when I login on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ there is no way of filing a new bug, and when I login on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/desktop/8 there is no way of starting a new thread. So the only way I can make ANYONE aware of the error is here:

The problem is simply that these 2 sentences:

If 0 it means that your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization.

If 1 or more it does - but you still need to make sure that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

Should have been:

If 0 it means that either your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization or you need to enable it in the BIOS.

If 1 or more it does.

MAYBE one could add:

- but you should still check that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: A few years ago, due to problems with spam IIRC, they restricted edit permissions on the community wiki to trusted users. That said, I do see a "New Topic" thread on the linked Ubuntu Discourse page. It might be that you're too new a user (and need to get to [Trust Level 1](https://blog.discourse.org/2018/06/understanding-discourse-trust-levels/#trust-level-1--basic) to start posting).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble. I've been there before.

That's a quirk of Ubuntu's contributor community numbers dwindling for the moment I'm afraid. We've not quite had the manpower to update the docs, though I believe [efforts have begun](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/outdated-documentation/22726/2) to figure out how to overhaul it.

For reference on where to send edits for the docs, the best thing to do is to drop an email in the [ubuntu-doc mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-doc). That's where people with edit access and/ are part of the community docs team would be willing to help patch in any mistakes.

Thanks for pointing this out!